# Flowchart to find the number of occurrences (binary search)

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-search, flowchart

I have never created a little complicated flowchart, so I'm a bit confused now.

This is the code that I wrote:

```
def binary_occurences(arr, target):

    start = 0
    end = len(arr)-1
    placement = -1
    occurence = 0

    while start <= end:
        center = (start + end)//2
        if target == arr[center]:
          placement = center
          end = center - 1
        elif target < arr[center]:

            end = center - 1
        else:
            start = center + 1

    if placement == -1:
        return 'your target element is not in the list'
    else:
        while (placement < len(arr) and arr[placement] == target):
            placement += 1
            occurence += 1

    print(f"Element {target} occurs {occurence} times")
```

based on this code, I made a flowchart

[flowchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cD64E.png)

But it seems like a little mess, so I am not sure If I am right, particularly under while loops.

Can anyone give me an advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not bad. But couple of pieces of advice:

- If you must do two (or more) things, and then go back to something else (like a loop), you don't have to make every element go back. Only the last one.
- If multiple things are going back to one (like multiple outcomes of the `if..elif..else` statements) going back to the loop condition, try to align them. It's okay if their arrows overlap.

Here's what I'm talking about: [my version of your flowchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJ2Jy.png). I've kind of neglected fonts, size, and alignment, but I think you probably have software which will take care of that.